# JavaScript file not loading in .jsp file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scala

Currently I'm programming in the front end and I have run into a problem where my javascript files dont load. My files are .jsp becauase of scala/scalatra backend. I have my index.jsp where I include my header file in the top and in the bottom I include my footer.

I include them like this:

```
<jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>
// CODE //
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>
```

My header looks like this:

```
<!-- HEADER -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/cssfile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cssfile.css">
</head>
<body>
```

And my footer looks like this:

```
  <!-- FOOTER -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My main.js looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
'use strict';
$(function() {

    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {

          if (
                  location.pathname.replace(/^//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^//,'')
                || location.hostname == this.hostname
            ) {

            var target = $(this.hash);

            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

            if ( target.length ) {

                  $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                  }, 1000);
                  return false;

            }

          }

    });

});
```

});

My file structure is like this:

```
css
  -cssfile1
  -cssfile2
js
  -jquery.js
  -main.js
header.jsp
index.jsp
footer.jsp
```

Mr src route shoulde be correct and when I insepect the source code of the site I can see the main.js file and click on it and it is the correct js.
I have tried console.log("test"); and nothing appears, so it does not load.
I added the jquery.js with the jquery javascript in it and added it first in the footer as you can see.

So what I want is that my main.js should load.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the resulting HTML actually being sent to the browser?  In the browser's debugging tools, are the requests for the `.js` files being made?  What is the server's response?  Is there another error in your `.js` preventing that `console.log("test");` from executing?  Show enough code to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

JSP EL provides a variable (${pageContext.request.contextPath}) that can be used at design-time to help resolve to the proper path at runtime. Try this might help, are you using the correct jquery libary?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/main.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: It did not work for me, my javascript still dont work and I don't get a response with console.log("test");

Comment: Are you using the correct jquery I added a CDN for you to try

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/main.js"></script>

That is how I have it right now in my footer, but i still dont work. In console I get: GET http://localhost:8080/js/main.js as an 404

Comment: The first link <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/main.js"></script> worked for me. Thanks!